# Write a program to accept a number from the user and count the zeros, odd digits and non-zero even digits from the entered number

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

The code doesn't count the 0 if 0 is the first digit. For example, if the input is 012 it returns the number of zeros as 0 instead of 1.

```
n=int(input())
str_number = str(n)
zero = 0
odd = 0
even = 0
for i in str_number:
    if int(i) == 0:
        zero += 1
    elif (int(i)%2) == 0:
        even += 1
    else:
        odd += 1
print(f"Number of odd digits:{odd}")
print(f"Number of non-zero even digits:{even}")
print(f"Number of zeros:{zero}")
```

Comment: `n=int(input())` Converting the input to `int` will remove the leading `0`. So skip the conversion to `int` and leave it as a string.

Comment: Why do you convert the input to an int and then convert it back to a string?

Comment: Realised the mistake, took the input as a string and the problem was solved!! Thank you all for the responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting int, to string, back to int.
This causes the 0 to be removed because 012 is actually just 12.

try

```
n=str(input())

#do stuff
for i in n:
    #do more stuff
```

Comment: Your description of the issue is spot on. pedantic, `input()` is a string to begin with

Answer (score 0):

```
n = input()

odd = 0
even = 0
zero = 0

for i in n:
    if int(i) % 2 == 0 and int(i) != 0:
        even = even + 1
    elif int(i) == 0:
        zero = zero + 1
    else:
        odd = odd + 1
```

Checking if `(int(i)%2) == 0` to determine if a digit is even. However, this condition will count all even digits, including zero. To count only non-zero even digits, you should modify the condition to check if `(int(i) != 0 and int(i) % 2 == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

According to your expectations, a dict initialized with zeros should do the trick:
The dict keys are the strings you want to print, but for readability appealing variables are used ^^
Then the *fromkeys* method sets default values (0).

Test within the for loop is implemented to:

- extract odd numbers,
- within even numbers, extract "0" from others.

```
odd = "odd digits"
zero = "zeros"
even = "non-zero even digits"
numberof = dict.fromkeys([odd, zero, even], 0)

n = input()
for i in n:
    if int(i) % 2 != 0:
        numerof[odd] += 1
    else:
        if i == "0":
            numberof[zero] += 1
        else:
            numberof[even] += 1

for category, count in numberof.items():
    print(f"Number of {category}: {count}")
```

Output:

```
Number of odd digits: ...
Number of zeros: ...
Number of non-zero even digits: ...
```